# Skull symbol no longer working after updating from TL16 to TL17

Tags: fonts

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{skulls}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{skulls}{m}{n}{ <-> skull }{}
\newcommand{\skull}{\text{\usefont{U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol{'101}}}

\begin{document}
    Here is a skull:
    $\skull$
\end{document}
```

stopped working after I had updated TeXLive to 2017 version.

The error is the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\skull ->\text
               {\usefont {U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol {'101}}
l.9     $\skull
            $
```

Though everything works with `\usepackage{skull}`, I don't want to use it because as advised in the answers to my old question, it isn't reasonable to load a package for one symbol and it also conflicts with some other packages.

Comment: this isn't a change. Are you sure the posted document worked in tl2016?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle maybe I am posting not the part that gives the error. Because in a large document I get an error `luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "Font skull not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
! Font \U/skulls/m/n/10=skull at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.`
And I am 100% sure that a document of mine stopped working after update.

Comment: the error in the comment is completely unrelated to the error shown by the example document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

luatex does not trigger `mktextfm` so if you take the document in Alan's answer and use with lualatex you get

```
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "Font skull not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
! Font \U/skulls/m/n/10=skull at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or ba
d.
```

But if you run it with pdflatex you get

```
...
kpathsea: Running mktextfm skull
...
```

and then after that the tfm is generated and the original document works also with lualatex

Answer (score 9):

The `\text` command comes from the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{skulls}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{skulls}{m}{n}{ <-> skull }{}
\newcommand{\skull}{\text{\usefont{U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol{'101}}}

\begin{document}
    Here is a skull:
    $\skull$
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, but that document doesn't compile with *any* version of TeX Live. Just for completeness, I tried with TL from 2012 to 2017 and the compilation always stops with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\skull ->\text 
               {\usefont {U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol {'101}}
l.9     $\skull
               $
```

This is clear, since `\text` needs `amstext` (which is loaded by `amsmath`).

If you don't want to use `amsmath` or `amstext` (but I see no reason to), you can define `\skull` in a different way:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\skull}{\ifmmode\mathskull\else\textskull\fi}
\newcommand\textskull{{\usefont{U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol{'101}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathskull{%
  \@check@mathfonts
  \mathchoice
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\sf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\ssf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{skulls}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{skulls}{m}{n}{ <-> skull }{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\skull}{\ifmmode\mathskull\else\textskull\fi}
\newcommand\textskull{{\usefont{U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol{'101}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathskull{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \mathchoice
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\sf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}
    {\mbox{\fontsize{\ssf@size}{\z@}\textskull}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a skull: $\skull$ but also in text \skull.

$A_{\skull}$

\end{document}
```

I believe that `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\text` is easier.

[image]

With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and a font that has the required glyph (Symbola is free):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fontspec,newunicodechar}

\newfontface{\skullfont}{Symbola}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\NewDocumentCommand{\skull}{}{%
  \text{\skullfont\symbol{"1F571}}%
}
\newunicodechar{}{\skull}

\begin{document}

Here is a skull: $\skull$ but also in text \skull.

$A_{\skull}$

Here is a skull: $$ but also in text .

$A_{}$

\end{document}
```

[image]